# Google IAM Used to authenicate end users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am trying to figure out if you can use Google IAM to authenticate users to a website I am hosting or is it simply used to allow Developer types access to the project in the cloud? I cannot find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Google IAM is not designed for website authentication. You will want to use an Identity Provider.

Google has Google Identity Platform.

> Google Sign-In is a secure authentication system that reduces the
>   burden of login for your users, by enabling them to sign in with their
>   Google Account—the same account they already use with Gmail, Play,
>   Google+, and other Google services.
>
> Google Sign-In is also your gateway to connecting with Google’s users
>   and services in a secure manner. You can give your users the
>   opportunity to pay with Google Pay, share with their Google-wide
>   contacts, save a file to Drive, add an event to Calendar, and more.
>   Integrate Google’s user-centric APIs and services inside your app to
>   help your users take action and convert.

[Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/)

Comment: Thanks for the clarity!